# Objective-C call class method on Class variable

Tags: objective-c, class

I need to call a class method on a variable of type Class, which I know holds a subclass of a base class, MyBaseClass...

```
- (void)foo:(Class)clazz {
  // Now i want to call +myClassMethod on clazz
}
```

I don't know if this is actually possible. If it is, is there a safer way to guarantee that clazz is actually a subclass of MyBaseClass?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-respondsToSelector:`, just like you would with any Objective-C object.  You can also use `+isSubclassOfClass:` to test whether the class is a subclass of another class.

```
- (void)foo:(Class)clazz 
{
    if ([clazz respondsToSelector:@selector(myClassMethod)])
    {
        [clazz myClassMethod];
    }
    else
    {
        // clazz does not implement that class method.
    }

    if ([clazz isSubclassOfClass:[MyBaseClass class]])
    {
        [clazz myClassMethod];
    }
    else
    {
        // clazz is not a subclass of MyBaseClass.
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a "not" missing in the first comment. I would edit it in, but edits have to be at least 6 characters and I don't want to change anything else in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ( [clazz isKindOfClass:[MyBaseClass class]] ) {
  [clazz myClassMethod];
}
```

Comment: `[clazz isKindOfClass:[MyBaseClass class]]` returns false here, since it's a Class itself, not an instance of one.

`[clazz myClassMethod]` DOES work. Thanks!

Looks like `[clazz respondsToSelector:@selector(myClassMethod)]` does the job.

firstStackOverflowExperience.setSuccessful(true);

Comment: My mistake. Darren's suggestion of isSubclassOfClass or respondsToSelector should work in its place.

Comment: -isKindOfClass: is an instance method, and would return NO in this case because clazz is not an instance of MyBaseClass.  Use + isSubclassOfClass: instead on class objects.  These are all declared in NSObject.h.